# How to include a vector 2 when serializing (jsoncpp)

Tags: c++, json, vector

I would like to convert a vector of Books to the json format with jsoncpp.
Using the model from here with a map [How to insert a map or vector to generate a json string (jsoncpp)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24138594/how-to-insert-a-map-or-vector-to-generate-a-json-string-jsoncpp) I did not find the way to get a string in json format

```
struct Book {
std::string book;     
std::string source;  
std::string brdsId;
}


std::vector<Book> book;
book.push_back(Book("EURO_SWAPS", "SUMMIT", "1233345"));
book.push_back(Book("US_SWAPS", "SUMMIT", "987654"))

Json::Value root;
root["root"] = "root";

Json::Value myVect;
for(std::vector<Book>::iterator it = book.begin(); it != book.end(); it++) {
myVect[std::to_string(*it)] ; // does not work
}

root["Books"] = myVect;
Json::StyledWriter writer;
string output = writer.write( root );
```

Should I put a double loop "for", once to get the book and the second one to catch its contenu ?
thank you very much

Comment: `Json::Value myVect;` and `myVect[std::to_string(*it)];`; what do you expect to happen at this stage?

Comment: Hi Caramiriel, I expected that the contenu of each book would be converted into a string for each iteration. I mean , I expected in my case 2 iterations and for each one inserting the 3 variables.
Actually I am little bit lost because the final idea is to have something like
{
"root" : "root",
"books" : { ["EURO_SWAPS", "SUMMIT", "1233345"],["US_SWAPS", "SUMMIT", "987654"] }
}

Comment: doig this:
   for(std::vector<Book>::iterator it = book.begin(); it != book.end(); it++) {
 //myVect[std::to_string(*it)] ; // does not work
 myVect[it->book];
 myVect[it->source];
 myVect[it->brdsId];
 }

I don't have the result expected which should be like a list : ["book","source","id"],["book2","source2","id2"]

Answer (score 4):

At the end I found it , this is the solution:

```
for(std::vector<Book>::iterator it = book.begin(); it != book.end(); it++) {
    Json::Value jsonVect;
    jsonVect.append(it->book);
    jsonVect.append(it->source);
    jsonVect.append(it->brdsId);
    root["testvect"].append (jsonVect);
}
```