# how to write a template converts vector to Json::Value (jsoncpp)

Tags: c++, templates

i wrote a template(like below) but it fails to compile

```
template<class t, template<typename> class iterable>
Json::Value iterable2json(const iterable<t>& cont)
{
    Json::Value v;
    for(const t& elt : cont)
    {
        v.append(elt);
    }
    return v;
}

std::vector<int> vec{1,2,3};
Json::Value v = iterable2json(vec)
```

error C3312: no callable 'begin' function found for type 'const std::_Vector_val<_Val_types>'

with[ _Val_types=std::_Simple_types ]

see reference to function template instantiation 'Json::Value iterable2json,std::_Vector_val>(const std::_Vector_val<_Val_types> &)' being compiled

with[ _Value_type=int, _Val_types=std::_Simple_types ]

error C3312: no callable 'end' function found for type 'const std::_Vector_val<_Val_types>'

with[ _Val_types=std::_Simple_types ]

error C2065: 'elt' : undeclared identifier

Comment: Could you please add the compiler error you are encountering?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that compiler can't deduce the type `t` as it is indirectly determined through the template template parameter. However, there is actually no need to do anything like that in the first place! The following works just fine:

```
template <typename Iterable>
Json::Value iterable2json(Iterable const& cont) {
    Json::Value v;
    for (auto&& element: cont) {
        v.append(element);
     }
     return v;
}
```

(well, since I don't have the `Json` library you are using I havn't tried to compile it but I'd think it should be fine).

Comment: It works. Thank you for your help, Dietmar.
I think i have perplexed this issue.