# Universal way to copy json arrays to C++ vector (jsoncpp)

Tags: c++, vector, jsoncpp

I found this soultion to convert any kind of iteratable (vector of bool's, vector of int's, etc.)  to a json array, refering to this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26773409/15205839)

```
template <typename iterable>
Json::Value iterable2json(iterable const& object) {
    Json::Value json_array;
    for (auto&& element : object) {
        json_array.append(element);
    }
    return json_array;
}
```

Since I am using vectors of ints, bools, floats etc. it is very helpful to simply pass the vector into the iterable2json function, to get an proper json array. Now I am trying to reverse this simple way, but only found this soultion, where I have to define wether the return value is a double/integer/bool etc.

```
void jsonarray2doublevector(Json::Value& json_array, std::vector<double>& vec) {

    vec.reserve(json_array.size());
    std::transform(json_array.begin(), json_array.end(), std::back_inserter(vec), [](const auto& e) { 
        return e.asDouble(); 
    });

}
```

This was the [original Post](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp/issues/1363) from github

**How can I simply pass any kind of vector to my function and determine the type? Like is it a vector of ints, or is it a vector of bools?**

Comment: I assume you don't know beforehand what kind of data is in the JSON array?

Comment: Maybe try to use `std::variant` in your vector, then `std::holds_alternative` to check the real type?

Comment: what is the question? Do you want to write a function that returns the right type based on the json array or is it ok for the caller to specify the type?

Comment: Because this JSON library apparently has separate functions that convert a value to each native type, a single template-based solution will not work. You'll just have to implement a couple of overloaded functions to get the same result. Do you know what overloaded functions are, in C++?

Comment: if you could tell me how I can pass any kind of c++ vector to a function an determine inside of the function wether its a vector of ints or a vector of floats, then I could handle the json specify type definition on my own (I updated the question)

Answer (score 2):

If its ok for the caller to decide what type of vector to transform to you can make the function a function template:

```
template <typename T>
void jsonarray2vector(Json::Value& json_array, std::vector<T>& vec) {

    vec.reserve(json_array.size());
    std::transform(json_array.begin(), json_array.end(), std::back_inserter(vec), [](const auto& e) { 
        return value_to_type<T>(e);
    });
```

Where `value_to_type` is a function template you need to specialize for the types you want to transform to. I am not aware of a simpler way to do that because `Json::Value` has only `asXYZ()` methods but no generic `as<T>()`.

```
 // type for partial specializations
 template <typename To, typename From>
 struct value_to_type_impl;

 template <typename From>
 struct value_to_type_impl<double,From> {
       To operator()(const From& f) { return f.asDouble(); }
 }

 // ...and similar specializations for the other types

 // function to be called
 template <typename To,typename From>
 To value_to_type(const From& f) { return value_to_type<To,From>{}(f); }
```

You can then call it like this

```
Json::Value json_array;
std::vector<T> vec;
jsonarray2vector(json_array,vec);
```

Since C++17 you can use `constexpr if` in combination with `std::is_same` to save some typing on the specializations. However, as getting a `T` from a `Json::Value` I would still suggest to stay with a `value_to_type` or similar for the conversion.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) I guess this is the best I can do to have a universal function :)